# What is the best way to deal with "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises" while using async/await inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have a small React project using Typescript and ESLint.  I'm making a fetch call inside useEffect to populate some results for a table that's displayed on page load.  I can successfully make the call and don't receive any errors other than the ESLint error message under `fetchSsidWhitelist()` saying:

> "Promises must be awaited, end with a call to .catch, end with a call
> to .then with a rejection handler or be explicitly marked as ignored
> with the `void`
> operator. (eslint@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises)

I can force the error message to go away using `void` or promise-chaining (options shown below) but I don't understand why I need either... Maybe I'm not seeing something.  If I do need to deal with an uncaught promise and I'm forced to use `.catch`, is there any way I can use `async`/`await` so I don't have to mix `async`/`await` with promise-chaining?

**ESLint Error Example:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchSsidWhitelist = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('/Admin/whitelisting/ssid-whitelist');

            if (!response.ok) {
                setShowErrorMessage(true);
                throw new Error(await response.text());
            }

            const data: SsidWhitelist[] = (await response.json()) as SsidWhitelist[];

            setResults(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('An error occurred during the fetch: ', error);
        }
    };

    fetchSsidWhitelist()
}, []);
```

**Option #1**:

```js
fetchSsidWhitelist()
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

**Option #2**:

```js
void fetchSsidWhitelist()
```

Update: I took @Jahedule Hoque's advice and assigned the data variable to `SsidWhitelist[]`, not sure what I was thinking when I assigned it as a `Promise`.  However, the proposed change did not change the original error about a floating promise.

Comment: The ESLint plugin cannot tell your `fetchSsidWhitelist` function won't throw. I'd suggest adding the `void`

Comment: @TalRofe what do you mean it won't throw?  Is it because the try/catch block?  Couldn't something happen while its calling the `fetchSsidWhitelist()` function?

Comment: I say that although your function never throws because of your try catch block, the plugin, I assume, cannot tell this is the case

Answer (score 0):

In this line, why you are forcing the response to be a Promise?

```
const data: SsidWhitelist[] = await (response.json() as Promise<SsidWhitelist[]>);
```

You can achieve your desired functionality by removing the promise.

```
const data: SsidWhitelist[] = await response.json();
```

Here is the full code

```
useEffect(() => {
    setColumnDefinitions([{ field: 'UserId' }, { field: 'UserName' }, { field: 'LeaNumber' }, { field: 'Email' }, { field: 'IPAddress' }, { field: 'PermissionLevel' }]);

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('/Admin/whitelisting/ssid-whitelist');

            if (!response.ok) {
                setShowErrorMessage(true);
                throw new Error(await response.text());
            }

            const data: SsidWhitelist[] = await response.json();

            setResults(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('An error occurred during the fetch: ', error);
        }
    };

    fetchData();

}, []);
```

Comment: If I remove the `as Promise<SsidWhitelist[]>` section I get, "Unsafe assignment of an `any` value.eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment)".

Comment: try with this
const data: SsidWhitelist[] = await (response.json() as SsidWhitelist[]);

Comment: I think assigning the response as `SsidWhitelist[]` is an improvement over assigning it as a promise but it didn't do anything about the original error.  I still get, "Promises must be awaited, end with a call to .catch, end with a call to .then with a rejection handler or be explicitly marked as ignored with the `void` operator.eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises)" under fetchSsidWhitelist() without `void` or `.catch`.